# Mock Google Cloud platform in google-cloud-java testing

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

cloud-java`library https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#authentication to create a subscription to`GCP`, and so far so good.

But now what I would like is to make an integration test where I can control the subscription works without have to go to the real `GCP`.

I've been looking in google without success, anybody know a way to mock a `GCP` to do this sort of testing.

I know I could use `Docker` to run one `GCP` for my testing, but I was trying to avoid that layer of complexity.

Regards

Comment: I have attempted a first answer but I might have misunderstood a few things. I was confused by your usage of the GCP concept and how you state that Docker would be a clear solution to your problem. If my answer does not help, please clarify why it doesn't and how Docker can help solve your issue. Cheers

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood you, but you want to have a way for testing the library in `https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#authentication`without having to send those requests to Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Exactly, send to my mock

Comment: Just to clarify your question, why you don't want to send the requests to a mock instad of sending to GCP?
Also, you mention something about _control subscription_, in which way you want to control a subscription or what you want to change of the subscription?
Do you have a link of documentation for the Docker method you've mentioned to figure out what you're expecting about the mock?
Does @MarCialR [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486073/13171940) fits in what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good amount of examples of how we should create Pub/Sub test cases in java can be found in [this directory](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/tree/main/google-cloud-pubsub/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1) of the Google Cloud Pub/Sub Client for Java. I haven't found there an example of how we would mock the creation of a Topic for example, so it is not an exhaustive list but it surely will help you make that first approach.